# Unable to connect user to Microsoft Exchange with Outlook 2007

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2007, email

I have a remote(VPN) user that is having problems connecting to Exchange after he had a power outage.

-I was able to ping the exchange server from his computer.
-I removed and re-added his profile and there are no issues when saving it.
-He is able to connect to OWA and exchange on his iPhone with no issues.

When Outlook opens I am getting this message:

> Cannot start Microsoft Office Outlook.
>   Cannot open the Outlook window. The
>   set of folders cannot be opened. You
>   must connect to Microsoft Exhange at
>   least once before you can use your
>   offline folder file.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using (and you likely are) a local .ost folder, rename it before starting outlook.  It may be corrupt from the abrupt shutdown.

Comment: I already recreated the profile. It should create a new .ost file.

Comment: Did you recreate the Outlook profile?  If so, then the ost was NOT recreated.  The ost is in a user directory and is not deleted when the Outlook profile is removed.  If you removed the Windows profile and recreated, the ost may have been recreated.  Humor me if you have no other options.

Answer (score 1):

Hold `CTRL` and right click the outlook icon in the taskbar, then select `Connection Status...` to view the method used to connect (TCP/IP or HTTPS).  If using HTTPS verify that your RPC settings are correct for the profile.  Are you using cached mode?

Comment: Yes. Using Cached exchange mode.

Answer (score -1):

Try this workaround, I have faced the same issue and this helped: http://insomniacgeek.com/cannot-open-your-default-e-mail-folders-you-must-connect-to-microsoft-exchange-with-the-current-profile-before-you-can-synchronize-your-folders-with-your-offline-folder-file/

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please edit your answer so that it stands on its own.